# How to convert typescript class to plain javascript object with class-transformer

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-transformer

I've some typescript classes instances in my angular app that I've to save to firebase. Firebase isn't supporting custom classes, so I found this: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer that seems well fitted for me.

So now I'm creating my object, and trying to convert it.

Here is my object.

```
export class Trip {
  id: string;
  owner: string;
  name: string;
  @Type(() => Date)
  startDate: Date;
  @Type(() => Date)
  endDate: Date | undefined;
  coverImageUrl: string;

  @Type(() => Itinerary)
  itinerary: Itinerary;

  constructor() {
    this.itinerary = new Itinerary();
  }
}

export class Itinerary {
  @Type(() => ItineraryStats)
  stats: ItineraryStats;
  @Type(() => Step, {
    discriminator: {
      property: '__type',
      subTypes: [
        { value: ActivityStep, name: 'ActivityStep' },
        { value: NightStep, name: 'NightStep' },
        { value: PointOfInterest, name: 'PointOfInterest' },
        { value: TravelStep, name: 'TravelStep' },
      ],
    },
  })
  steps: Step[];

  constructor() {
    this.steps = Step[0];
    this.stats = new ItineraryStats();
  }
}

export class ItineraryStats {
  ///In days
  duration: number;
  //in hours
  driveTime: number;
  //in kilometers
  driveDistance: number;

  averageDriveDistancePerDay(): number {
    return this.driveDistance / this.duration;
  }
  averageDriveTimePerDay(): number {
    return this.driveTime / this.duration;
  }
}


export abstract class Step {
  @Type(() => Date)
  start: Date;

  @Type(() => Date)
  end: Date;
  duration: number;
  enforcedStartStop: boolean;
  warning: string;
}

export class ActivityStep extends StopStep {
  duration: number;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.id = Guid.newGuid();
  }
}


export class NightStep extends StopStep {
  nightNumber: number;
  numberOfNight: number;
}

export class PointOfInterest {
  @Type(()=>PointOfInterest)
  type: PointOfInterest;
}


export class TravelStep extends Step {
  @Type(() => TravelMode)
  Mode: TravelMode;
  PolyLines: string;
}
```

I'm creating one "trip" and trying to convert it:

```
const trip = new Trip();
trip.owner= firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
trip.name= action.name;
trip.startDate = action.startDate,
trip.endDate = action.endDate;
console.log(trip);
const converted = classToPlain(trip)
```

But I get this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
    at TransformOperationExecutor.js:207
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (TransformOperationExecutor.js:207)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (TransformOperationExecutor.js:266)
    at ClassTransformer.classToPlain (ClassTransformer.js:10)
    at classToPlain (index.js:8)
    at Object.toFirestore (trips.firestore.ts:16)
    at ma (index.cjs.js:15983)
    at n.set (index.cjs.js:15359)
    at AngularFirestoreDocument.set (angular-fire-firestore.js:512)
```

The object I just created:
[image]

I guess either my object is in an improper state or I've something poorly defined, but I can't find what?

Comment: Please share `Type` decorator

Comment: @captain-yossarian this decorator is from the library I linked: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/src/decorators/type.decorator.ts

Comment: You should create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in the definition of `Itinerary`, more specifically the code line `this.steps = Step[0];` which sets the variable to undefined and most likely wasn't intentional. The `class-transformer` library can deal with property `steps` being an empty array, array of steps, or not existing in the first place but crashes when the value is set to undefined.

```
export class Itinerary {
  @Type(() => ItineraryStats)
  stats: ItineraryStats;
  @Type(() => Step, {
    discriminator: {
      property: '__type',
      subTypes: [
        { value: ActivityStep, name: 'ActivityStep' },
        { value: NightStep, name: 'NightStep' },
        { value: PointOfInterest, name: 'PointOfInterest' },
        { value: TravelStep, name: 'TravelStep' },
      ],
    },
  })
  steps: Step[];

  constructor() {
    // Step[0] causes the crash, because its undefined, either dont set it or 
    // set it to this.steps = []
    this.steps = Step[0]; 
    this.stats = new ItineraryStats();
  }
}
```

**More details:**
Due to the use of discriminators on property `steps` the corresponding logic kicked in and compared the constructors defined under `subTypes`, with the constructor of the current value to find the correct subtype name:

```
    if (this.transformationType === TransformationType.CLASS_TO_PLAIN) {
      subValue[targetType.options.discriminator.property] = targetType.options.discriminator.subTypes.find(
        subType => subType.value === subValue.constructor
      ).name;
    }
```

[link to github](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/e34e1ae160b0cd3340558c03b017dee3b2dcaa60/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts#L71-L75)

`Step[0]` being undefined eventually made this line `subValue.constructor` crash.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed this and it now seems to work. I'm sorry, I'm kind of a beginner in the javascript(and I'm still not sure why doing `this.steps = Step[0]` would result in an undefined array instead of a empty array like java/c# ^^. Anyway, your suggestion(`this.steps = []`) work, I still have other issues with dates(why dates are so hard to handle in javascript when they are so easy in other languages)